# How to load a modal in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an index that i have a add button when press load a modal.

index.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Foods</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button color="primary" (click)="showModal()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

this is the index page ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AddPage } from '../add/add.page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: 'index.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['index.page.scss']
})
export class IndexPage {

  constructor(private modalController: ModalController) { }

  async showModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: AddPage,
    });
    await modal.present();
  }
}
```

so when the user click showModal load the modal.

Now this is my add modal module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AddPage } from './add.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AddPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [AddPage]
})
export class AddPageModule {}
```

This is my add page td.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add',
  templateUrl: './add.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.page.scss'],
})
export class AddPage implements OnInit {

  constructor() {

  }
```

The problem when i go to the index page the Modal is already loaded. I can't even see the Index page anymore. Its like the Modal is being routed to the Index page.

Comment: did you try my answer?!

Answer (score 0):

In your modal html, add the following:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
<ion-title>Foods</ion-title>
<ion-buttons slot="primary">
  <ion-button color="primary" (click)="dismissModal()"> Dismiss
  </ion-button>
  </ion-buttons>
 </ion-toolbar>
```

Then in the ts, add the following:

```
dismissModal() {
 this.modalController.dismiss(null);
}
```

This will let you dismiss the open modal.